# Writing a string[] to a file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write some values i get from some dynamically created EditTexts to a file.The EditTexts are in an Array list and i get their values and put them in a string[].
I then need to put those values in a file like this :

`product[1] : quantity[1] : price[1]`

```
product[2] : quantity[2] : price[2]
```

.....

`product[n] : quantity[n] : price[n]`

I tried this :

```
 private void writeToSDFile(){
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
    totalc.append("\nExternal file system root: "+root);
    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");

    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        pw.write("Total : ");
        pw.println(totaltest + price[1]);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you" +
                " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the   manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    totalc.append("\n\nFile written to "+file);
}
```

I tried putting price[1],to test if it works and it doesn't.
It gives me the following error in LogCat :

```
06-13 21:23:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(25345): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 21:23:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(25345): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1
06-13 21:23:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(25345): at com.example.testlayout.MainActivity.writeToSDFile(MainActivity.java:89)
```

So ? how can I send those values to my file ?
Thanks !

EDIT :
This is where and how i declare my arrays :

```
private String[] cant = new String[allcant.size()];
private String[] pret = new String[allpret.size()];
private String[] prod = new String[allpret.size()];

public void calculeaza() {

    totaltest = 0;

    String[] prod = new String[allprod.size()];
    for (int m = 0; m < allprod.size(); m++) {

        prod[m] = allcant.get(m).getText().toString();
        if (prod[m].matches("")) {
        //  Toast.makeText(this,
                //  "Ati omis cantitatea de pe pozitia " + (m + 1),
                //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            prod[m] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }


    String[] cant = new String[allcant.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < allcant.size(); j++) {

        cant[j] = allcant.get(j).getText().toString();
        if (cant[j].matches("")) {
        //  Toast.makeText(this,
                //  "Ati omis cantitatea de pe pozitia " + (j + 1),
                //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cant[j] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    String[] pret = new String[allpret.size()];
    for (int k = 0; k < allpret.size(); k++) {
        pret[k] = allpret.get(k).getText().toString();
        if (pret[k].matches("")) {
            //Toast.makeText(this,
            //      "Ati omis pretul de pe pozitia " + (k + 1),
            //      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pret[k] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < allpret.size(); l++) {

        Float temp = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);
        alltotal.add(temp);
        totaltest = totaltest + temp;

        TextView totalf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        totalf.setText(String.format("Total: %.2f", totaltest));




    }
}
```

The problem might be that i declare it twice ? Once outside the method and once inside ? But if i don't declare it inside,it crashes.Can anyone tell me why ?

Comment: You don't have any values. The length of your arrary is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The error you have indicates that you are in fact accessing price[1] but the length of price[] is 0, in other words empty.

Answer (score 1):

From your logcat output we can tell that the issue is not necessarily with your file writing code, but with your array. The array is empty, but you are trying to reference an element from it. In order to properly test, try adding this code above `pw.println(totaltest + price[1]);`:

```
price = {111,222,333};
```

The result should print the value of totaltest + 222;

Answer (score 1):

Your array is empty. I would recommend you to check why.

Arrays are created in this way:

```
int[] name = new int[size];
```

You probably set the `size` to 0 or initialize the array in this way:

```
int[] name = new int[]{}; // creates an empty array
```

Comment: `String[] pret = new String[allpret.size()];` You probably have no elements in `allpret`, so the `size()` result is `0` and therefore you create the empty arrays :)

Comment: Nope.I changed it to     `pw.println(allpret.size());` and it prints the number of EditTexts i have.In my test,the number was 3.

Comment: But you didn't include the code where you initialize the `price` array.